# how do i enable Line2 raycast

Tags: line, raycasting

i am using fat line example from three.js 91 version.
i found that raycating is not able to identify object intersection.

earlier THREE.Line was able to identify line intersection points,please give me direction to solve the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: You will need to post your code and a much more complete description.  As it is, I don't think anyone is going to be able to help with your description the way it is. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Problem is solved,i am using webgl_lines_fat.html example to draw lines.i was not able to locate line object using mouse event.so i had overwritten raycast function at THREE.Line2 and used instanceStart , instanceEnd values to identify intersects.thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an extension to the [@eswar-reddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9524475/eswar-reddy) solution of overriding the raycast function in `Line2.js` to work with `instanceStart`. Here is the snippet of code I would change:

```
if ( geometry.isBufferGeometry ) {

            var index = geometry.index;
            var attributes = geometry.attributes;
            var positions = attributes.position.array;

            if ( index !== null ) {

                var indices = index.array;

                for ( var i = 0, l = indices.length - 1; i < l; i += step ) {

                    var a = indices[ i ];
                    var b = indices[ i + 1 ];

                    vStart.fromArray( positions, a * 3 );
                    vEnd.fromArray( positions, b * 3 );
```